# SQL Query duplicate record

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I had following table.Oquer works fine but it shows complete duplicate record.I want all record with name to be appear single  time

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
    ( `Name` varchar(7), `Address` varchar(55), `City` varchar(15),`Contact` int,`timestamp` int)
;

INSERT INTO Customer
    (`Name`,`Address`, `City`, `Contact`,`timestamp`)
VALUES
    ('Jack','New City','LA',79878458,456125),
    ('Joseph','New Lane23','LA',87458458,794865),
   ('Rosy','Old City','Paris',79878458,215125),
   ('Maria','New City','LA',79878458,699125),
   ('Jack','New City','LA',79878458,456125),
   ('Rosy','Old City','Paris',79878458,845125),
   ('Jack','New Main Street','New York',79878458,555525),
     ('Jack','New City','LA',79878458,456125),
   ('Rosy','Old City','Paris',79878458,845125),
   ('Jack','New Main Street','New York',79878458,555525),
   ('Joseph','Near Bank','SAn Francisco',79878458,984521)

;
```

Query:

```
select t1.*
from customer t1 join
(select Name, max(`timestamp`) as maxstamp
 from customer
 group by Name) xx 
 on t1.Name = xx.Name
 and t1.`timestamp` = xx.maxstamp;
```

Comment: You want Maximum Timestamp data for individual user?

Answer (score 0):

```
Use DISTINCT keyword

select DISTINCT t1.* from customer t1 join (select Name, max(timestamp) as 
maxstamp from customer group by Name) xx  on t1.Name = xx.Name
and t1.timestamp = xx.maxstamp;
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite 3.7.11 or later (Android Jelly Bean or later), you can simply use MAX() with GROUP BY:

```
SELECT Name, Address, City, Contact, MAX(timestamp) AS timestamp
FROM Customer
GROUP BY Name;
```